# display an image full screen on the click of a button Android

Tags: android, image, button, listeners

I'm a total noob to android dev and have nominated myself to write a special needs education app for my final year college project. one of the elements I'm trying to develop is a set of flash cards (png images) each card can be displayed full screen by clicking its corresponding button on the apps homescreen. I can do this in Java easily but after 2 days of googleing and trying various tutorials the image will still not display.
I'm getting pretty worried that if something this straight forward is difficult in android then the project is DOOMED, please help

picView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.pic_view);
        picView.setBackgroundColor(0);

```
    Button pickBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.pick_btn);
    pickBtn.setOnClickListener(this);

    Button loadBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.load_btn);
    loadBtn.setOnClickListener(this);

    Button appBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.app_btn);
    appBtn.setOnClickListener(this);

    picView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    picView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
}
```

Heres my onClick method

public void onClick(View v) {
        if(v.getId() == R.id.app_btn) {

```
        picView.loadUrl("file:///res/drawable-hdpi/image1.png");

    }
```

Comment: Please show the code you have, only the bit where you try to display the image.  And of course the project is not doomed.  It's easy to do this - you just don't know how yet.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you don't have problems displaying buttons and receiving clicks on them.

So to display an image full screen, a solution is to

- create a special activity (a seconde one)
- then give it a style to put it full screen (basically set the widht, height and remove the title bar),
- then give it a layout with a single imageView that will fill its parents width and height.

Then learn how to pass parameters from one activity to another using intents. Pass the id of the resource to display and display it.

Comment: Thanks Snicolas. I think I get that, its trying to get my head around the the project structure and XML (i've no XML experience) I'll see if I can find some code examples online.